# Dynamodb One table design - scan and filter with limit approach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

So I'm following the one table design and the PK keys that are with the below format

```
P#product1
P#product2
P#product3
W#warehouse1
W#warehouse2
P#product4
....
```

With this query pattern "get all products" , I need to run a scan to get all records "`begins_with = P#`" and I'm not sure if this is the ideal approach.
I understand Scan is resource-consuming (and I would love not to have to rely on it)
Not to mention that if I want to put in limit & pagination, the scenario becomes even more cumbersome (as limit is applied before the filter). E.g: the first scan with a limit of 10 may return only 3 products, next one may only return 2 , etc..)

Is there a more straight forward approach? I was hoping to at least scan through say 87 products out of 1000 records, and will still be able to get 9 pages of 10 products per instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across other forum topics and found this solution that we can utilise Dynamodb Global Secondary Index
Basically:

- We'll set up an attribute , say entitytype(values can be product,warehouse...)
- And create a Global Secondary Index with
  GSI PK : to set to that entitytype
  GSI SK : set to the original PK
- We'll end up having the below in this GSI
  product P#product1
  product P#product2
  warehouse W#warehouse1

We can then query against this GSI using Query entitytype=product